# 2D Multiple Type List

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array

I need to create a list containing both strings and integers and then another list containing all of those lists. How would I go about this in java? I am trying to create a list of different items, each of the items have certain properties. E.g. one item entry could be ("Sword", int damage, int weight). And then all of those items are stored in a list. The lists do not have to be editable once they are created. It is just a table that I can retrieve information about different items from. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of inserting strings and integers in an array you can define a bean that holds these values for you:

```
public class YourClassInsteadOfArray{
     private String stringDesc;
     private int damage;
     private int weight;

     //getters & setters
}
```

and after defining a number of instances you can store them in a List<YourClassInsteadOfArray>

Comment: Short, concise, to the point, you're doing much better than most with your reputation